# Injecting service in Quartz job in Grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

developing application using `Grails 2.5.1` i used [Quartz plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/quartz?skipRedirect=true) , and created a job successfully , but when i inject a service in this job i get `org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException`

here is the Job's code:

```
class EveryMonthJob {
def usersUtilsService
static triggers = {
    cron name: 'EveryOneMonthJob', cronExpression: "* 31 2 L * ?" 
}

def execute() {

    usersUtilsService.testMe() // getting the exception here 
        }
}
```

Comment: Is the NPE "cannot call testMe() on null object" or something else?  I also have services injected into 2.5.1 quartz jobs and they work, so I'm suspicious that there may be something else going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are any number of reasons that might not work.  If you are creating an instance of the job yourself (as opposed to Spring creating the instance and subjecting it to dependency injection), that would explain why the reference is null.  Another explanation could be that you have the property name wrong.

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/sherifquestion.  That is a Grails 2.5.1 app that does just what you are describing and it works fine.  See https://github.com/jeffbrown/sherifquestion/blob/e0179f836314dccb5f83861ae8466bfd99717995/grails-app/jobs/demo/EveryMonthJob.groovy which looks like this:

```
class EveryMonthJob {

    // generally I would statically type this property but
    // am leaving it dynamically typed top be consistent with
    // a question being asked...
    def usersUtilsService

    static triggers = {
      simple repeatInterval: 5000l // execute job once in 5 seconds
    }

    def execute() {
        usersUtilsService.testMe() // this works fine
    }
}
```

Comment: Guys , it worked successfully after running `clean` command on the grails project . i think the project needs to be cleaned that's all .